# How can read checked row cell value in WPF DataGrid (Bind source from data context) using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

Here my DataGrid in wpfwin.xaml. I want to collect "Challan_No" value in list but i can't do this ..please help me

```
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Chalaan ID" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding   Id, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Challan No" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Challan_No, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Company" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Organization_Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Client" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Organization, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Date, Mode=OneWay}"/>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="select"  Width="100" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox  x:Name="ckselect"  ></CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And  here, I tried some code to get it in .cs page

```
                    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
                    for (int i = 0; i < myGrid.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        CheckBox mycheckbox = myGrid.Columns[5].GetCellContent(myGrid.Items[i]) as CheckBox;
                        if (mycheckbox.IsChecked == true)
                        {
                            int inde = this.myGrid.SelectedIndex;
                            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)myGrid.Items[inde];
                            object ch = drv[1];
                            list.Add(ch);
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you could simply use a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` instead of adding a `CheckBox` inside a `DataGridTemplateColumn` :

```
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Chalaan ID" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding   Id, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Challan No" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Challan_No, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Company" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Organization_Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Client" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Organization, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Date, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="select" Width="100" />
           </DataGrid.Columns>
         </DataGrid>
```

and to get the list of checked items:

```
 var SelectedList=new List<YourDataGridItemType>();
    for (int i = 0; i < MyDataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                var item = MyDataGrid.Items[i];
                var mycheckbox = MyDataGrid.Columns[1].GetCellContent(item) as CheckBox;
                if ((bool)mycheckbox.IsChecked)
                {                 
                    SelectedList.Add(YourDataGridItemsList[i]);
                }
            }
```

where YourDataGridItemsList represent the list of objects that your DataGrid is Binded to .

Comment: How to enable checkbox to Checked

Comment: do you mean to make the default value of the DataGridCheckBoxColumn IsChecked To True ?

Comment: I implement your Code in my page bu tits not enable to select them

Comment: Could you show me how you are defining your DataGrid (Xaml)?

Comment: Mr. Joseph, check-box is not bind with database (Column), it's using for select row DataGrid row witch are bind with database. My code Implementation same as your given Solution ...

Comment: Mr. @mukesh_mourya i can't see where the problem is !! <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="select" Width="100" /> isn't binded to any dataBase Attribute ...it is used Only to select the elements  to add to the SelectedList, THIS IS EXACTLY WHAT YOU ASKED FOR !

Comment: extremely Sorry.. Its My fault to unable to select checkbox due to           IsReadOnly="True"

Comment: One More thing.... please help to select selected cell value. i tried this code                                                 DataGridCell drv = (DataGridCell)myGrid.Columns[1].GetCellContent(i);
  SelectedList.Add(drv .ToString());

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best if you added an IsSelected property to whatever type it is you are displaying and then just TwoWay bind that property to the checkbox column. That way you can simply do this to get the selected elements:

```
mycollection.Where(x=>x.IsSelected);
```